# R: error pops up when calculating confidence intervals with RMediation::medci

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have the following data:

```
exp_med_b <- c(-0.0594832340,-0.0219711830,-0.0418851800,0.0004572729,-0.0011745170)
med_out_b <- c(-0.02325445,-0.03738470,0.12305580,3.40118200,0.88303590)
exp_med_se <- c(0.040328500,0.013646880,0.030657290,0.001533312,0.002025108)
med_out_se <- c(0.01300451,0.08911688,0.07536918,1.21814000,0.54391590)
```

and am trying to run the following

```
library(RMediation)

confidence_intervals <- medci(mu.x=exp_med_b,
                              mu.y=med_out_b,
                              se.x=exp_med_se,
                              se.y=med_out_se,
                              type='dop')
```

but the following error pops up:

**Error in integrate(gx, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, z = z) :
maximum number of subdivisions reached**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get the same error. Efforts to debug have failed. My next step would be to contact the package maintainer. `maintainer(RMediation)`

Comment: Thanks, @IRTFM, I just realised that I need to run medci one-by-one for each set of values, i.e. `medci(mu.x = exp_med_b[1], mu.y = med_out_b[1], se.x = exp_med_se[1], se.y = med_out_se[1], type = 'dop')`. This will return a list including the 95% confidence intervals, indirect effect estimate, and standard error.

Comment: So maybe use `mapply` with those vectors?

Comment: This is a good idea!